# Docker apt-get fails inside minikube

Tags: macos, docker, debian, apt, minikube

I am trying to build a docker image inside minikube on a mac for testing, but when I run apt-get update I get a bunch of failed to fetch messages.

```
Err http://repo.mysql.com jessie InRelease

Err http://repo.mysql.com jessie Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to repo.mysql.com:http:

Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie InRelease

Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease

Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie Release.gpg
  Cannot initiate the connection to httpredir.debian.org:80 (2001:41c8:1000:21::21:35). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:41c8:1000:21::21:35 80]
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates Release.gpg
  Cannot initiate the connection to httpredir.debian.org:80 (2001:41c8:1000:21::21:35). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:41c8:1000:21::21:35 80]
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease

Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates Release.gpg
  Cannot initiate the connection to security.debian.org:80 (2610:148:1f10:3::73). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2610:148:1f10:3::73 80]
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/dists/jessie/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to repo.mysql.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to httpredir.debian.org:80 (2001:41c8:1000:21::21:35). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:41c8:1000:21::21:35 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to httpredir.debian.org:80 (2001:41c8:1000:21::21:35). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:41c8:1000:21::21:35 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to security.debian.org:80 (2610:148:1f10:3::73). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2610:148:1f10:3::73 80]

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

However when I build the same image on my host it works fine.
Did I miss a network setting when I started minikube that is blocking these sites?

to start minikube I run `minikube start --vm-driver=xhyve`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was the xhyve driver. When I switched to using virtualbox everything worked out great.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid re-building the docker image you can transfer an image built on your local machine into the minikube VM with:

```
docker save <image> | minikube ssh docker load
```

From: https://twitter.com/markoluksa/status/828996606477422592